# How can I link a JS File from Parent Directory (Localhost)

Tags: html, localhost

Let me start with file management. So, there is a main.js and a main.css, both of them having the styles all the HTML Pages have. Now, there are HTML Pages inside child folders, so the directory looks like this:

```
/The Project
    /main.js
    /main.css
    /Home
        /index.html
        /styles.css
    /Study
        /index.html
        /styles.css
        /scripts.js
```

When I run the HTML files as a file in the browser, it works perfectly. However, when I run it using `python3 -m http.server`, it does not link the CSS and JS files that are in the parent directory.

Thank you for answering in advanced!

Home/index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home - Plompy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css">
    
    <script src="../main.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="overflow-x: hidden;">
    <div class="nav"><li class="options">Home</li><li class="options">Study</li><li class="options">Discussion</li><li class="options">About</li><li class="options" style="color: rgb(66, 174, 213);">Sign Up!</li></div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">Pompy - The Future of Creatures</h1>
        <img src="academicean.png" alt="Academicean Logo" style="float:right;width:400px;height:400px">
        <h2 class="body">HAHAHA LOL</h2>
        <h1 class="title">Contact Us:</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <h4 class="body">Best experiences may be with a computer, or laptop. Although compatible with other devices such as the hand held phone, not that the experience won't be as smooth as with a laptop.</h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Study/index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home - Academicean</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css">
    
    <script src="../main.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="overflow-x: hidden;">
    <div class="nav"><li class="options">Home</li><li class="options">Study</li><li class="options">Discussion</li><li class="options">About</li><li class="options" style="color: rgb(66, 174, 213);">Sign Up!</li></div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">Academicean - The Future of Reviewers</h1>
        <img src="academicean.png" alt="Academicean Logo" style="float:right;width:400px;height:400px">
        <h2 class="body">Academicean, which is the combination of Academic and Ocean, provides much resources to study or to review a topic. Whether thats Mathematics, English, Sciences or any of your academic subjects, you may review for it RIGHT HERE! There will also be a comment section, where you may gather some more opinions about a certain topic, and ask some questions if confused. So what are you waiting for? Log in or Sign up to be able to get started!</h2>
        <h1 class="title">Contact Us:</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <h4 class="body">Best experiences may be with a computer, or laptop. Although compatible with other devices such as the hand held phone, not that the experience won't be as smooth as with a laptop.</h4>
    </div>
</body>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Study - POmpley</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="../main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav"><li class="options">Home</li><li class="options">Study</li><li class="options">Discussion</li><li class="options">About</li><li class="options" style="color: rgb(66, 174, 213);">Sign Up!</li></div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">GOogle LOL</h1>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" id="searchbar" onfocus="change_note()">
            <h2 id="note">Type something to search</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we please see you index.html file?

Comment: ok, sure man i will just edit it

Comment: "However, when I run it using python3 -m http.server" — What directory are you in when you run that command?

Comment: In the parent directory @Quentin

Comment: @tdserapio — Define "the parent directory" please. You've given all the directories names in the example (and they are all parent directories to something!). Which one of those?

Comment: the The Project is the main directory

Comment: So the URL you are visiting is `http://localhost/Home/` which renders an HTML document  and if you were to visit `http://localhost/main.js` you would get an error page and not some JS?

Comment: from home.html, I cannot access the main.js